# Combining Streams and Iteration in STXXL

Tags: c++, stxxl

[STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) supports a streaming model of data processing. STXXL data can either be processed by iterating through it (e.g. using `stxxl::for_each`), or by converting to a stream mode (e.g. using `streamify()` where such stream transforms can be composed for efficient processing. The stream results can be converted back to iterators using `materialize()`.

I have a bunch of stream transforms, that I want to apply to an input stream. However, I do not need to store the result in any output "container".
What I need is a `materialize`-like function that just drives the stream without taking any output iterators - essentially like `stxxl::for_each`.
Is there such a similar function in STXXL?

Naturally, I can write custom "do-nothing"-output-iterators and pass these to `materialize()`, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`stxxl::stream::discard`](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/tags/1.4.0/group__streampack.html#ga93090b87eee59a8bd0d3314abe22304b). Which takes a stream and throws away the results.

Comment: Bingo! Just what I was looking for. Thanks!